# AngularJS based web application design

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I want to make a very scalable web application. Backend is rest based APIs.
For frontend, I want to use angularJS. For that I have two options -
1. Use AngularJS + Grunt (deployement) + npm ( for package installation)
So it will be a standalone angular js app.

2. Node JS server, on that I host my angularJS app.

Which one of the above two option will give be better result ?

Comment: You did not give a choice. You just had 2 steps for a complete web app. Start reading docs and writing code to understand the mechanics.

Comment: there is a choice, to use nodejs as server. Or not to use nodejs server. As already i am having my own rest based apis for backed , my concern is, do i need nodejs in front end app.

Comment: What do you mean nodejs front end app? A webapp usually runs in a browser. If you are running outside a browser it is no longer a web app.